# tizen BLE scanner webapplication

Tags: javascript, web, tizen

im trying to develope a tizen application with BLE scanner and in device.manufacturerData.data is returning "䱄~ " and JSON.stringify(device.manufacturerData.data) is returning "䱄~\u0003"

in the API documentation, it says that manufacturerData.data is a DOMstring, how can i covert it into something readable ?

Comment: It seems UniCode ....

Comment: Is the API broken? Manufacturer data should of course be some kind of byte array.

Comment: @Emil i have reported the this issue on tizen forum, you can view the below link https://developer.tizen.org/comment/26505#none, and some one did confirm the same issue, im trying replicate this app https://www.tizenexperts.com/2017/08/track-ble-devices-ble-beacon-scanner-app-gear-s2-s3/ , i don't know if there is work around

Comment: I created a similar app for one of my client around 2 years back. I can check my code and get back to you.

Comment: @shreeramk i would really appriciate it if you could help me with that